# Boost threads in asio program crash everything when using same object

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, boost-asio

I am writing a dfs using boost::asio based on boost's example of chat server(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp). Processing of each message to master server starts with reading the message from socket by a Session object(which is basically the same as the chat_session object in the example above), which is than sent to a Server_Group object for parsing.

So, when there're two different messages from different sockets, they are at first simultaneously processed by different session objects and than they call the one server_group object, and than everything crashes.

I think that I avoided race conditions in the server_group object, but I am fairly new to concurrent and asynchronous programming, so I basically don't have any idea what went wrong.

The method that is called from both sessions and where it all supposedly crashes(I printed out thread's "location" in code and the crash happens when one thread is inside the parse_possible_sequence method, and when the other is trying to call it):

```
void Server_Group::parse_possible_sequence(server_participant_ptr server, std::string message, int header_code){
    if (header_code == 2) {
        if (strcmp(continuous_messages[server].c_str(), "") == 0) {
            parse(server, message);
        } else {
            continuous_messages[server] += message;
            parse(server, continuous_messages[server]);
            continuous_messages[server] = "";
        }
    }
    else{
        continuous_messages[server] += message;
    }
}
```

server_participant_ptr -- a base class of the Session class.

Server_Group's fields:

```
    std::unordered_map<int, server_participant_ptr> participants_;
    enum { max_recent_msgs = 100 };
    chat_message_queue recent_msgs_;
    std::atomic<int> current_id = {0};
    std::unordered_map<server_participant_ptr, std::string> continuous_messages;
    Server_Group *other_group_;
```

So my question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just because a C++ program crashed inside a particular function doesn't mean that's where the problem is. C++ doesn't work this way. The problem can be anywhere, which is why stackoverflow.com's [help] directs you to create a [mcve] that anyone can cut and paste, compile, execute, and reproduce your problem. Without a [mcve] that someone can use to reproduce your problem, it is unlikely that anyone will have enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you! I will try and post a better example soon.

Comment: @twodragon What protects `continuous_messages` from being read by one thread (say in `if (strcmp(continuous_messages[server].c_str()...`) while another this is modifying it (say in `continuous_messages[server] += message;`)?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, I thought that string returned by ```continuous_messages[server]``` should be different for different ```server``` objects, so there should not be any race conditions.

Comment: @twodragon The issue isn't the string returned, it's `continuous_messages` itself. That is an object that can be accessed by one thread while another thread might be modifying it. Once you get a reference back from `continuous_messages[server]` you could release the lock, but you need protection when accessing the collection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Got it, thank you!